Why electric field lines inside are parallel inside a cylindrical capacitor?
Why electric field lines are parallel inside a cylindrical capacitor?
Please help me in this

They aren't. They point radially outward or inward depending on the charge.

Since the surface area of the outer cylinder wall is greater than the surface area of the inner cylinder wall while the amount of charge is equal and opposite, the field lines can’t be parallel. The lines need to be closer together near the inner surface where the charges are closer together than the outer surface where the charges are farther apart.
Hope this helps.
